# How to set 0 value in table at doctrine 2 to column? It's saving like null

Tags: doctrine-orm, null, entity, persist

Hi I'm created application with table which is one of column is can't be null.
When I'm persisting value with 0 value. The doctrine is saving it to database as null value.
I'm trying to save column sort_id value in my code.
How to save 0 value as 0 integer value?

Here is my code

```
  namespace cms\models\Entities;

  use \cms\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM; 
  use \cms\Doctrine;
  use \cms\models\Entities; 
  /**
  * @Entity
  * @Table(name="vkladki")
  */
  class Vkladki{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id; 

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $cat_id;  

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $sort_id;  

 public function setSortId( $sort_id){
        $this->sort_id = $sort_id;
    }
```

Comment: I found my mistake. It was in my php code. I had to save Entity value as null instiade 0. Sorry people!